# disable link if not validated

Tags: javascript, validation

i have a anchor link and i do not want it to be enabled if some validations are not correct.basically i am a newbie to javascript so forgive my noobness

below is the example:

```
<form name="myform">
<select name="test">
    <option >choose one</option>
    <option value="one">oone</option>
        <option value="two">two</option>
        <option value="three">three</option>
</select>
    <a href="#goThere"> clickMe</a>
</form>
```

in my real practice, i am using some bootstrap.js but i figured out it is a general problem.

 i want link to be disabled if i select nothing in select box.
fiddle for reference:http://jsfiddle.net/UGJN4/

Comment: i searched over internet, please mention reason for vote down

Comment: I think you can do it by using `php` or `server side language` is better, because more secure to do that

Comment: @LionKing actually i am bound to do it by JS or some jQuery, but not php. thanks for taking interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using jQuery. First give it a class something like :

```
<a href="somewhere.html" class="bb">clickMe</a>
```

Then, try this if validation are not correct :

```
$('a.bb').removeAttr('href').attr('href', 'javascript: void(0)');
```

If correct :

```
$('a.bb').removeAttr('href').attr('href', 'somewhere.html');
```

Comment: ty bro!! you just stopped titanic from sinking. God bless you

Comment: @SachinVerma You are welcome.. please take +1 to your question from me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this in javascript :

Put id into anchor tag :

```
 <a id="alink" href="#goThere" target="_blank"> clickMe</a>
```

Javascript Code :

```
var flag=1;
document.getElementById("alink").onclick = function() {
    console.log("hello");    
    // Validate here. Change the value of flag 1<=>0 for testing.
    // 0 => for true condition
    // 1 => for false condition, it will redirect on new tab.
    if(flag==1){
        return false; 
    }
};
```

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/UGJN4/2/